# Magento2 : Set dynamic email subject via template

Tags: magento2, module, email

I am working on Magento 2. I want to send the dynamic subjects E-mail. I am implementing one module.

So, How to do this via code in custom module ?

Comment: Please add some context so that one can help you better. How are you sending the emails? Are you talking about subjects defined in transactional email templates? What do you have already? What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

I am Implementing a custom module and sending email by code mentioned in this Link

https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/

To set Dynamic Subject I replaced

`@subject Subject Of your email` by `@subject {{var subject|raw }}@` in my html file.

Which I put under `NameSpace\Modulename\view\frontend\email\filename.html`

Value to subject variable is passed from Helper file which is mentioned in the https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/ link.